# After upgrade from Fedora 23, Fedora 24 touchpad does not work while logged in

Tags: touchpad, fedora-24

I upgraded my Fedora 23 system, which worked most excellently for the last year or so, to Fedora 24 using the (relatively new) `dnf system-upgrade` mechanism.  There were some minor glitches which were easy to do, though hard to find online.

```
package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=2
dnf remove google-earth       # this allows system-upgrade to complete
dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=24 --best --allowerasing --setopt=keepcache=True
dnf system-upgrade reboot
```

After it rebooted, it is thoroughly Fedora 24, except the touch pad and the two buttons below it do not work—but *only* when logged in!    When logged out, (or before logging after the system first boots) they work fine.

I have looked for a matching solution already posted, both here and at [AskFedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/90173/tap-to-click-missing-from-fedora-24/) where there are many touchpad-related issues in Fedora 24, but not quite the same.  I tried many of them anyway, such as:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad edge-scrolling-enabled true
dnf install xorg-x11-drv-libinput
dnf reinstall xorg-x11-drv-synaptics
dnf install xf86-input-synaptics
dnf install synaptic.x86_64 xorg-x11-drv-synaptics.x86_64
```

The `xinput list` output is

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and touchpad properties (`xinput list-props 10`):

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (133):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (135): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (269): 0
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (270): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (271):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (272):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (273):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (274):   0
    libinput Accel Speed (275): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (276): 0.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (277):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (278):   0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (253): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (254):    1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (255):    0, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (279): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (280): 0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (281):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (282):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (283):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (284):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (285):    1
    Device Node (256):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Device Product ID (257):    2, 7
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (286):   <no items>
    libinput Horizonal Scroll Enabled (258):    1
```

Alas, most of these solutions target the touchpad device driver (or kernel) not talking to the touchpad.  In my case, since **the touchpad works** when not logged in, there must be some Xwindows or Gnome setting which interferes with the touchpad input.

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you create a fresh test account and log in to that?

Comment: @mattdm:  it works great.  When I logged out and back into my usual account, the touchpad ceased to work.  Apparently the problem is user account-related.

Comment: So, if you go to the mouse & touchpad settings applet, is Touchpad set to _off_, by any chance? Just knocking some of the easy ones off the list, here.... :)

Comment: @mattdm:  It was off.  Turning it on (which I am sure I had done before) makes it work just fine.  Thanks.  Write an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Nice. Computers, amirite? Presumably that toggles something you could have also gotten with gsettings... I'll look that up later and put it in the answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to get an easy thing out of the way: go to the Mouse & Touchpad settings applet and make sure that Touchpad isn't set to *Off*.